# How can I make this with react fullcalendar ? Scroll with right and left mouse?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I use `fullcalendar` and I have seen its ability to use the left mouse click to smoothly scroll top and left and use the right mouse click to select dates. Which props do I need for this to make it like this? I made a video to illustrate what I want:

https://streamable.com/47orjz

at current my code looks like this:

```
        <FullCalendar 
          schedulerLicenseKey="xxx" 
          plugins={[ resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin ]}
          initialView='resourceTimelineWeek'
          height='auto'
          stickyFooterScrollbar
          editable={true}
          selectable={true}
          selectMirror={true}
          scrollTime='00:00'
          resources={[
            { id: 'a', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium A' },
            { id: 'b', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium B' },
            { id: 'c', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium C' },
            { id: 'd', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium D' },
            { id: 'e', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium E' },
          ]}
          resourceGroupField='building'

        />
```